# Creating a Google-Drive app, how to get started?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm about to create a Google Drive app, like for example "Google Drive Viewer" that can be opened over a `file -> Open with -> Appname` or even better, through the context-menu by right-clicking it. I've searched through the internet but i just couldnt found any good resource on how to achieve this?

Allready tried Google-Apps-Scripts, but this seems to be limited to Google-Docs-documents. Did i overlook something or is it really as this hard to find? Can someone explain me succinctly how i can get started?

To clarify, i'm not talking about the Google-Drive-client. I'm talking about the apps that you can use over google-chrome

**UPDATE**: would it be also possible to extend the functionality of the Google-Drive-Viewer? For example with the scripts, because you can also extend the google-docs-editor's.

Comment: [This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0HVJMIeb3aE&list=PL68F511F6E3C122EB&index=5&noredirect=1) is about using Apps Scripts in combo with the Drive interface. About supported file types, I'm not really clear on the question. Are you trying to build a viewer with Apps Scripts that has edit capabilities for more file types than the native Drive editor/viewer?

Comment: the video seems pretty much that for what i was looking for. i will check it out and let you know